# How to break a while true with keyboard interruption?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

How can I break a while True if I press a key?, and if it is possible, how can I break a while True if a press an **x** key (e.g. `intro`)?.

```
while True:        
    if something is pressed:
        print("STOP")
        break
    do_something()
```

I tryied with inputs but you can't put:

```
while True:
    i = input() or None if program wait > 3 seconds. # > = more than
    if != None:
        print("STOP")
        break
    do_something()
```

Input stop all the while waiting for answer, and i don't want that.

**PD:** I use win 10 64-bits, python 32-bits 3.6, terminal.

**PD2:** Before post this question I search more about it, i found:

```
while True:
    try:
        do_something()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

But this only stop with `Ctrl + c`, not other keys.

Comment: For the Windows console you can use `msvcrt.kbhit()` to check for a key press. It's console only; it won't work in GUI programs such as the IDLE shell.

Comment: @eryksun, I was re-reading my questions and I saw that you post this comment but you don't made a question. You could post that like an answer, I used that and it worked.

Comment: You will probably need an external library for this.

Answer (score 0):

This only works in Windows:

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        break
```

The [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/msvcrt.html) provide a list of functions capables of process key inputs. `msvcrt.kbhit()` check if a key was pressed and it's waiting for been read and return true or false based on that.